# Synchronizing commits with all tools together: SVN/GIT Jira FishEye TeamCity Sonar

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube, teamcity, jira

This is workflow I would like to achieve

1. Developer commits the story to Branch 1
2. if is finished(Set to status done):

   a. Code Review(FishEye)

   b. Manual Tests(Jira)

   c. ESLinter(Javascript) + frontend/backend tests (Team City)

   d. Java quality checks (SonarQube)
3. Automatically code goes to Branch 2

Do anyone had such experience with synchronizing all of the tools? - I just need to know if this is possible to do or not.

I will be happy to see yours opinions/advices

As I understand I need to check if all environments has proper api and are able to make communication between them?

Comment: Two notes: 1) by "Sonar(Java)" you mean that you want to run an analysis _and check the quality gate status_? If so, you might want to make that explicit in your scenario 2) SonarJS can check your JavaScript code during your SonarQube analysis. :-)

Comment: Yes, using sonar I would like to check quality for java code and depending o n that take an action

Comment: Perhaps you should [edit] your question to be explicit. :-)